# Can I move Blazor WASM index file content to the server-side?

Tags: blazor-webassembly

So we moved the content of the index file to a new MVC index-file on the server side.

The Blazor.webassembly.js is pointing to wwwroot which in the end is the wwwroot in the client side wwwroot.

It is working. But does anyone know if there could be an issue with doing this?